# How can i compare 2 maps in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, string-comparison

### **(question) Long Pressed Name:**

Your friend is typing his name into a keyboard.  Sometimes, when typing a character c, the key might get long pressed, and the character will be typed 1 or more times.

### You examine the typed characters of the keyboard.  Return True if it is possible that it was your friends name, with some characters (possibly none) being long pressed.

**My Doubt:** :
i tried to solve this question with c++ STL maps but i am getting the wrong answer for this test case :
name ="saeed"

### typed ="ssaaedd"

here is my code :

```
bool isLongPressedName(string name, string typed) {

    unordered_map<char,int>m1,m2;
    for(int i=0;i<name.size();i++)
    {
        m1[name[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<typed.size();i++)
    {
        m2[typed[i]]++;

    }
    if(m2.size()!=m1.size()) return false;
    int b=0;
    for(int a=0;a<m2.size();a++)
    {
        if(typed[a]!=name[b] ||m2[typed[a]]<m1[name[b]] )
        {
            return false;
        }



        if(m2[typed[a]]>m1[name[b]])
        {
            return true;
        }

        b++;
    }

    return true;
```

---

please help me solving this problem.

Comment: I would advise against using a map for this. It loses all information about the original order of the characters, so (for example) it will say that `sade` and `edsa` are the same, even though they're obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way, I tested it and isLongPressedName("s", "sd") correctly yields false.

```
bool isLongPressedName(string name, string typed) {
    if (name.size() >= typed.size()) return false;
    bool long_pressed = true;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < name.size() && j < typed.size()) {
        if (name[i] == typed[j]) {
            if (i < name.size() - 1) ++i;
            ++j;
        } else {
            if (i > 0 && name[i-1] == typed[j]) {
                ++j;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return long_pressed;
}
```